# Check that a Clojurescript jar file is working

Tags: jar, clojurescript

I have some Clojurescript source files that output messages to the browser console on a timer. Eventually I would like to make a Clojars library from these files. So far I have created an uberjar using lein. All the user of this library would need to do is `:require` a namespace from the library, and messages should be emitted to the browser console. Seeing these messages is the "all working fine" test I want to perform.

In other words how do I check that the jar file I have created works? Can I start off with a fresh lein project and just put the jar file in some special 'un-managed' directory and `:require` the namespace? Actually I don't think you can do such a thing with lein, hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `project.clj` file already with the line

```
(defproject bigco/biglib "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT”
...
```

run

```
lein install
```

This will build the JAR and install it in your local Maven repo.

Then in your new project, add that dependency and run it.

Answer (score 0):

If your jar (definition of jar includes uberjar of course) does not come neatly from a lein project then an alternative is to use Maven 2 directly:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=./my-deps.jar -DgroupId=my-deps -DartifactId=my-deps -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Here `mvn` will store the jar in your local `.m2` maven repository. Once stored you can use this jar in any lein project on your machine by referring to it in the dependencies section:

```
[my-deps "1.0.0"]
```

Maven [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) for this.